# Help me to split string with Regular Expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

```
CriteriaCondition={FieldName=**{**EPS**}**$MinValue=(-201)$MaxValue=(304)$TradingPeriod=(-1)}
```

Help me to get the first word which ends with the first word "={" & get the next following word which ends with "}".

The result must be:

```
Word1 = "CriteriaCondition"
Word2 = "FieldName={EPS}$MinValue=(-201)$MaxValue=(304)$TradingPeriod=(-1)"
```

And with the string "FieldName=(EPS)$MinValue=(-201)$MaxValue=(304)$TradingPeriod=(-1)", help me to split to pairs:

> FieldName EPS
>
> MinValue -201
>
> MaxValue 304
>
> TradingPeriod -1

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do it cleanly with regexp. Unless the second match will always end near the string end.

Comment: You have `FieldName=(EPS)` on the third time. How much nesting are you expecting? Will you have escaped `=` or `$` signs in your values? Is that the whole string, or is it a part from a bigger string?

Comment: Are those ** around EPS going to be in the input and you want them stripped out or are they just in there in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a job for [.NET captures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures.aspx). In contrast to many other regex flavors, .NET remembers all captures of a repeated capturing group, not just the last one. I don't have VS installed here, so I can't test this yet, but try the following:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(subjectString, 
    @"(.*?)     # Match any number of characters and capture them
    =\{         # Match ={
    (           # Match and capture the following group:
     (?:        # One or more occurences of the following:
      (?>[^$]+) # One or more characters except $, match possessively and capture
      \$?       # Match the delimiting $ (optionally, because it's not there after the last item)
     )+         # End of repeating group
    )           # End of capturing group
    \}          # Match }
    ", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
Console.WriteLine("Matched text: {0}", match.Value);
Console.WriteLine("Word1 = \"{0}\"", match.Groups[1].Value);
Console.WriteLine("Word2 = \"{0}\"", match.Groups[2].Value);    
captureCtr = 0;
foreach (Capture capture in match.Groups[3].Captures) {
    Console.WriteLine("      Capture {0}: {1}", 
                             captureCtr, capture.Value);
    captureCtr++; 
}
```

Comment: Nicely done. I thought of adding a solution with nothing but splits and trims, but I don't think it will be very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

The regex for the first split is:
^([^=]+)={(.*)}$

It containts:
- start of line
- a first group of any character except = (Word1)
- the characters ={
- the remaining of the string (Word2)
- the character }
- end of line

Then you can split Word2 into parts separated by the character $, and apply a similar regex (without { and }) to each part

Answer (score 0):

This regex will get you most of the way there (and let you get a hold of the stuff you're interested in using [named capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)

```
@"(?<criteria>[^=]+)\=\{((?<params>[^$]+)(\$|}))+"
```

However, I assume a lot of the information in the string you don't actually care about so it would be better to just get rid of it outright and then parse the string from there.

Something along these lines would very clear about what exactly you're trying to accomplish (if you ever need to go back and make changes to it):

```
var temp = "CriteriaCondition={FieldName=**{**EPS**}**$MinValue=(-201)$MaxValue=(304)$TradingPeriod=(-1)}";

var startToken = "={";
var paramString = temp.Substring( temp.IndexOf( startToken ) + startToken.Length );
var cleanParamString = Regex.Replace( paramString, @"[*{}()]", "");

var parameters = cleanParamString.Split('$');
```

would give you a string array with the following rows

```
FieldName=EPS
MinValue=-201
MaxValue=304
TradingPeriod=-1
```

and you can manipulate them much more easily from there.